# How to set constraints on UIPanGestureRecognizer?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, autolayout, uigesturerecognizer

I have a view controller (green background) with a child view controller (red and blue) within it like so:

[image]

I use Auto Layout to determine the position of the child view controller like so:

```
func addConsttraints(){
    childController.view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    childController.view.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.heightAnchor, multiplier: 0.6).isActive = true
    childController.view.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
    childController.view.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
    childController.view.bottomAnchor.constraint(lessThanOrEqualTo: view.bottomAnchor, constant: 50).isActive = true
}
```

Further, I set Auto Layout constraints within the child view controller to position its subview (tableHeaderView and tableView) like so:

```
func addConstraints(){
    tableHeaderView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    tableHeaderView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor).isActive = true
    tableHeaderView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
    tableHeaderView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
    tableHeaderView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 44).isActive = true



    tableView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    tableView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: tableHeaderView.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
    tableView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
    tableView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
    tableView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
}
```

Right now I have set up a pan gesture recognizer on the `view` of my child view controller and am able to move it vertically:

```
  func didPan(gesture: UIPanGestureRecognizer){
    let translation = gesture.translation(in: self.view)
    switch gesture.state{
    case .began:
        print("Pan gesture recognizer began!")
    case .changed:
        let newPoint = CGPoint(x: view.center.x, y: view.center.y + translation.y)
        view.center = newPoint
    default:
        print("Default!")
    }
    gesture.setTranslation(CGPoint.zero, in: self.view)
}
```

My question is, is there a way to to set constraints on a pan gesture recognizer to have a maximum / minimum when moving the view associated with it? For instance, I want my minimum to be when the `tableHeaderView` is at the bottom of the screen like so:

[image]

At this point I don't want the user to be able to move the view controller further down.

And Finally, I want the maximum to be when:

[image]

Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Hi @A.Jam are you looking for something like this, https://github.com/CSStickyHeaderFlowLayout/CSStickyHeaderFlowLayout

Comment: You can't set constraints on a gesture, but you can set boundaries on the "translation point". Work those boundaries (bounds is a better word but I both do and do not want to confuse things with a view's bounds) into your constraints, animations, and sure, gestures.

Comment: @Mukesh, I agree that this open source code looks like something that would work, but the biggest issue is that it is written in Objective-C. From the sounds of the OP, just about everything is written already.

Comment: @A.Jam do little google for ParallaxHeader for uitableview swift, i am sure you got ideas.